# How to solve a system of ODEs with Scipy when the variables in the equations are autogenerated

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy, ode

I'm generating a system of ODEs in the form of a list of equations where the variables are `sympy.Symbol()`, for example `[3*sympy.Symbol('x')**3+sympy.Symbol('y') , sympy.Symbol('x')-sympy.Symbol('y')**4]`.

So using this example, I can solve this system through the code

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol  
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def kin(t, z):
    x, y = z
    eqs = [3*x**3+y  , x-y**4]
    return eqs

y0 = [0, 10]
t = np.linspace(0, 10000, 10000)
sol = solve_ivp(kin, [0, 10000], y0, dense_output=True)
print(sol.sol(t).T)
plt.plot(t, sol.sol(t).T)
plt.show()
```

And it will give this result https://i.stack.imgur.com/plzXU.jpg

But since the variables of `x` and `y` are in reality generated by a different code, I figured I could do

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol  
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dic = {'x': Symbol('x'), 'y': Symbol('y')}
vars = ('x', 'y')
#eqs =[3x^3+y , x-y^4]
eqs = [3*dic[vars[0]]**3+dic[vars[1]], dic[vars[0]]-dic[vars[1]]**4]

def kin(t, z):
    dics = {}
    for v in range(len(vars)):
        dics[vars[v]] = z[v]

    for e in range(len(eqs)):
        eqs[e] = eqs[e].subs(dics)
    return eqs

y0 = [0, 10]
t = np.linspace(0, 10000, 10000)
sol = solve_ivp(kin, [0, 10000], y0, dense_output=True)
print(sol.sol(t).T)
plt.plot(t, sol.sol(t).T)
plt.show()
```

Where it merely replaces the values of `x` and `y` from the first part by `z[0]` and `z[1]` but the output of this code is completely different https://i.stack.imgur.com/AusEu.jpg

I dont see where the issue is and would appreciate if anyone code point out where the problem is or help me find a way to evaluate these auto-generated systems of ODEs .

Comment: For that purpose you have the function `lambdify` and related in sympy that compile sympy expressions to python functions using numpy or to C or Fortran functions. Also, your symbolic variables are rather heavily packaged, you could just as well use `x,y = symbols("x y")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting that results is because you are overwriting `eqs` inside `kin` at each iteration. Also, as mentioned by Lutz, you should use `lambdify` which is going to convert symbolic expressions to numerical functions so that they can be evaluated by Numpy (much faster).

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol  
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dic = {'x': Symbol('x'), 'y': Symbol('y')}
vars = ('x', 'y')
eqs = [3*dic[vars[0]]**3+dic[vars[1]], dic[vars[0]]-dic[vars[1]]**4]
# convert symbolic expressions to numerical functions
eqs = [lambdify(list(dic.values()), e) for e in eqs]

def kin(t, z):
    # evaluate each numerical function with the current values
    return [e(*z) for e in eqs]

y0 = [0, 10]
t = np.linspace(0, 10000, 10000)
sol = solve_ivp(kin, [0, 10000], y0, dense_output=True)
plt.plot(t, sol.sol(t).T)
plt.show()
```

This will give you the first picture you posted.